# Adding a button in the bottom of a TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, three20

I'm trying to add a button on the bottom of a TableView, without any success.

The idea isn't to use the tableFooterView property, as that doesn't show the button in a fixed position.

My idea is more along the lines of the Facebook application's Notifications bar on the bottom.

I'm using Three20.

Any pointers on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add button to the view below your tableview but ensure your table height is less than the position you are adding the button,this way your can scroll table above button & your button will always be visible

Answer (score 0):

Just embed custom view over your tableview.i mean on the bottom of tableview.so the tableview will scroll and the view don't.

Comment: I'm not using Interface Builder in this project.

Comment: Add a subview to your table view in the exact position.

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIView as the footerView and then add the UIButton to the UIView.

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question, the idea isn't to use the tableFooterView.